# Importing binary data to parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to import data to parse.com so I can test my application (I'm new to parse and I've never used json before).

Can you please give me an example of a json file that I can use to import binary files (images) ?

NB : I'm trying to upload my data in bulk directry from the Data Browser. Here is a screencap : i.stack.imgur.com/bw9b4.png

Answer (score 0):

In parse docs i think 2 sections could help you out depend on whether you want to use REST api of the android sdk.

rest api - see section on POST, uploading files that can be upload to parse using REST POST.

SDk - see section on "files"

code for Rest includes following:

use some HttpClient implementation having "ByteArrayEntity" class or something

Map your image to bytearrayEntity and POST it with the correct headers for Mime/Type in httpclient...

```
            case POST:
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); //urlends "audio OR "pic"
                httpPost.setProtocolVersion(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1,1));
                httpPost.setConfig(this.config);
 if ( mfile.canRead() ){                
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mfile); 
                    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel(); // Get the file's size and then map it into memory
                    int sz = (int)fc.size();
                    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sz);
                    data2 = new byte[bb.remaining()];
                    bb.get(data2);
                    ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(data2);             
                    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    fis.close();                                        
                } 
,,,

request.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/*") ;

pseudocode for post the runnable to execute the http request
```

Comment: sorry my question was not clear enough..actually I'm trying to upload data in bulk directrly from the Data Browser. I did it with a json file and it works fine for my strings, numbers etc..but I can't find the right code to use to upload 'File' types. I will add a  screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The only binary data allowed to be loaded to parse.com are images. In other cases like files or streams .. etc the most suitable solution is to store a link to the binary data in another dedicated storage for such type of information.